# How can I display two rows in the same UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to show two rows of text in the same Table Row of a `UITableView`.

Is this possible to do?

I've tried different things, but I'm not able to find anything about it or figure it out. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    phonesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (phonesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    HLPFoundPhones *p = (HLPFoundPhones *)[appDelegate._phones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found on location (",p.x,@",",p.y,@") on date ", p.date];

    cell.textLabel.text = p._name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you already have some code? Please show us, it's easier to give you hints how to solve your problem.

Comment: see while outputting to a row for UITable i m using..

'cell.textLabel.text = p._name;'

now i want to output suppose p.x to the same cell... how can i do it.. Both are of NSStrings... sry i m a newbie..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the different style in Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1), what you may want is the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle (Figure 1-7 in the guide). Please have a look.

You can set the second label with `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"my text"`.

You've got to change this line

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

to

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

using the right style: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

**EDIT**

To format a string like you described in your comment:

```
NSString *location = @"a Location";
NSString *date = @"20m ago";
NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ on %@", location, date];
```

**EDIT 2**

```
NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found on location ("%f","%f") on date %@", p.x, p.y, p.date];
```

Please have a look at [String Programming Guide / Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) for more detail on how to format numbers etc.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];}phonesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (phonesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];HLPFoundPhones *p = (HLPFoundPhones *)[appDelegate._phones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = p._name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"joke";
    
    
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
'
is this correct ..?
bcoz i m unable to run it... i cant see the shorter text..

Comment: Please edit your own question and put the code there and format it with the {} button. In these comments some breaklines are missing.

Comment: Thanks nick.. just one more thing.. i want to show two strings in the second line.. like suppose two strings location and time..
I want to show it as..
found on <location> on <time>;

any help with that plz..?

Comment: Added an example, have a look at NSStrings class documentation.

Comment: plz check the question again.. m i doing it right.. bcoz i m not getting any output..

Comment: Where do your locations come from, is this longitude and latitude? Can you add code on how to retrieve them? A placeholder to replace in an NSString with format is %@ not @ and they can only be replaced with objects, there are more like %f for float and %d for integers.

Comment: for the time being i m taking them as strings also... p.x is the longitude and p.y is the latitude..
p.date is date but not able to put it somehow though.. can u plz edit the code..
Working on the code... as i told u i m a newbie..